# Can't Update UI from Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, polymorphism

I have a subclassed `UIViewController`. I have 24 playing cards on it that start out all face down. As I click on each card, they need to 'flip over', which really means that I am changing their background image from black to white. However, when I click on a card, I can't get the background image to change in the UI. And yes, I know for sure (because I've done it in another class) that the image exists and has the correct name.

I can see from NSLog calls that my code is executing, but I am confounded about why my UI won't update. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

---

Super Class

CardGameViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Deck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"

@interface CardGameViewController : UIViewController

// protected (for subclassing)
- (Deck *) createDeck; // abstract

- (void) updateUI;
- (NSString *) titleForCard:(Card *) card;
- (UIImage *) backgroundImageForCard:(Card *) card;
- (NSMutableArray *) cardsSelected;
- (void) setCardsSelected:(NSMutableArray *)cardsSelected;
- (UILabel *) recentCardLabel;
- (void) setRecentCardLabel:(UILabel *)label;
- (NSInteger) gain;
- (UILabel *) matchAttemptLabel;
- (CardMatchingGame *) game;

@end
```

CardGameViewController.m

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"

@interface CardGameViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cardsSelected;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *recentCardLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *matchAttemptLabel;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger gain;
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController

- (CardMatchingGame *) game
{
    if (!_game) {
        _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc]
                 initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count]
                         usingDeck:[self createDeck]];
    }

    return _game;
}

- (Deck *) createDeck  // abstract
{
    return nil;
}

- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.gain = -self.game.score; // capture previous score

    NSUInteger chosenButtonIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender];

    [self.game chooseCardAtIndex:chosenButtonIndex]; // note that this will update the game score

    self.gain += self.game.score; // increment gain by updated score
    self.gain += [self.game getGuessPenalty]; // add back the penalty for guessing

    [self updateUI];
}

- (void) updateUI
{
    int i=1;
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) {
        NSLog(@"%d", i++);
        NSUInteger cardButtonIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton];
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:cardButtonIndex];
        [cardButton setTitle:[self titleForCard:card] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cardButton setBackgroundImage:[self backgroundImageForCard:card] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isMatched;
    }

    self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];    
}

- (NSString *) titleForCard:(Card *)card {
    return card.isChosen ? card.contents : @"";
}

- (UIImage *) backgroundImageForCard:(Card *) card {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:card.isChosen ? @"cardfront" : @"cardback"];
}

@end
```

---

Sub Class

SetGameViewController.h

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"

@interface SetGameViewController : CardGameViewController

@end
```

SetGameViewController.m

```
#import "SetGameViewController.h"
#import "SetCardDeck.h"

@interface SetGameViewController ()
@end

@implementation SetGameViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateUI];
}

- (Deck *) createDeck
{
    return [[SetCardDeck alloc] init];
}

- (void) updateUI
{
    [super updateUI];

    self.recentCardLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recent Cards:"];
}

- (NSString *)titleForCard:(Card *)card
{

    NSString *string;

    string = @"A";

    return string;

}

- (UIImage *) backgroundImageForCard:(Card *)card
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"];
    if (!image) NSLog(@"no such image");
    else NSLog(@"image found");
    return image;
}
@end
```

The output from my two NSLog commands looks like:

```
1
image found
2
image found
...
24
image found
```

so I know that my code is executing in the proper sequence, subclass hierarchy is correct, etc. I can even get label text on my UI to update. But I just can't get the background images on these cards (UIButtons) to change. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks. And sorry for the long post. It's kind of a needle in a haystack, and I can't find the needle.

Comment: Where are you changing the `card.isChosen` flag?

Comment: That happens in another class. Even if I take out the ternary operator and just force `return [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardfront"`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure you updateUI is getting called from the main thread. Set a breakpoint and check the call stack or add an assertion, `NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"Not on the main thread");`

Comment: I added the NSAssert, and it seems to be on the main thread. Also verified this with a break point and looked at the call stack. Still clueless. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, shouldn't your subclass call `[super backgroundImageForCard]` ?

Comment: No. By having the method declared in the subclass, I'm overriding the super class method. The only reason that I know of to call a super class method is if there is code there that you want to execute before executing code specific to the subclass. In my case, my subclass method completely overrides the superclass method. Although, in this case, the code is essentially redundant, so I don't even really need a subclass method at the moment (I will as I build this out more, which is why I have it there).

Comment: But then you never get the correct image back based on the isChosen property. Isn't that what goes wrong, if I read your question correctly?

Comment: See my comment above. Even if I change the method to just say `return [UIImage imageName:@"cardfront"` it still doesn't work. In fact, I can comment out the entire superclass method, and I still have the same problem. As you can see, I know my subclass method is the one that is running based on the NSLog output.